# Something wrong with passing parameter to Url.Action method

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, http-post, http-get

I'm trying to write Update function via ajax.
These are my controller methods:

```
    [ActionName("UpdatePhoto"), HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdatePhotoPostViewModel(PhotoViewModel photo)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return PartialView("UpdatePhoto", photo);
        TempData["Photo"] = photo;
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }

    [ActionName("UpdatePhoto"), HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UpdatePhotoGetViewModel(PhotoViewModel photo)
    {
        if (TempData["Photo"] != null)
            photo = TempData["Photo"] as PhotoViewModel;
        return PartialView(photo);
    }
    public ActionResult Photo(PhotoViewModel photo)
    {
        if (TempData["Photo"] != null)
            photo = TempData["Photo"] as PhotoViewModel;
        return PartialView("PhotoSummary", photo);
    }
}
```

And View classes:

```
//PhotoSummary
@model PhotoAlbum.WEB.Models.PhotoViewModel
<div class="well">
    <h3>
        <strong>@Model.Name</strong>
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary">@Model.AverageRaiting.ToString("# stars")</span>
    </h3>
    <span class="lead">@Model.Description</span>
    @Html.DialogFormLink("Update", Url.Action("UpdatePhoto", new {photo = @Model}), "Update Photo", @Model.PhotoId.ToString(), Url.Action("Photo"))
</div>

//Main View
@model PhotoAlbum.WEB.Models.PhotoListViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Photos";
}
@foreach (var p in @Model.Photos)
{
    <div id=@p.PhotoId.ToString()>
        @Html.Action("Photo", new {photo = p})
    </div>
}
```

Here my DialogFormLink helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DialogFormLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string dialogContentUrl,
     string dialogTitle, string updateTargetId, string updateUrl)
{
    TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("a");
    builder.SetInnerText(linkText);
    builder.Attributes.Add("href", dialogContentUrl);
    builder.Attributes.Add("data-dialog-title", dialogTitle);
    builder.Attributes.Add("data-update-target-id", updateTargetId);
    builder.Attributes.Add("data-update-url", updateUrl);
    builder.AddCssClass("dialogLink");
    return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
}
```

The problem is that object photo in `UpdatePhotoGetViewModel` method is `null`.
But I passed the model here:

```
@Html.DialogFormLink("Update", Url.Action("UpdatePhoto", **new {photo = @Model}**), "Update Photo", @Model.PhotoId.ToString(), Url.Action("Photo"))
```

Why this parameter wasn't injected?

Comment: What is `DialogFormLink()`? (its not part of MVC).

Comment: @StephenMuecke added `DialogFormLink` class.

Comment: Its unclear what your trying to do here. A get method should not have your model as a parameter. And what is the point of sending a model to the voew and then sending it all back again unchanged. You should be just sending an `id` property an getting the model again based on the `id`.

Comment: If you did want to do the then its `new { Model }` (not `new { photo = @Model }` but not only will it generate an ugly query string, it will fail if the model contains any properties which are complex objects or collections, and your could exceed the query string limit and throw an exception.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just don't wanna make a new request to the server for getting an object Photo 'cause I have this object in main view. Is it possible to avoid this operation? I can change the model after I click "Update" (it calls an ajax dialog form).

Comment: There are many reasons that your code can fail. Just pass the `id`. If you dont want to make another database call to get the object, then put it in `Session` and get it from there.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I mean I can make a request in HttpGet method (if method recieve an id): _photoAlbumService.FindPhotoById(recievedId) but what I really want to recive this object from view or whatever where I have the access to get it.

Comment: Do you mean you want a javascript object of your model in the view without make a call to the server? If so you can use `Json.Encode(Model)` to assign it to a javascript variable

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for your reply! I just get my model from the server by got photoId from view. Now I have another problem:
when I click on the link twice without refreshing the page no jquery dialog appears (by the second time), it just redirects me to the action page. Could you help me?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I will create a new branch for the last question. You can post your comments as answer.

Comment: @StephenMuecke here the new branch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335280/no-jquery-dialog-appears-when-i-click-on-the-link-twice-without-refreshing-the-p

Comment: `@Html.Action("Photo", new {photo = p})`
This means your are passing `Photo`but
`public ActionResult Photo(PhotoViewModel photo)
{...}` accept `PhotoViewModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass the model back to a GET method, your code would need to be

```
@Html.DialogFormLink("Update", Url.Action("UpdatePhoto", Model), "Update Photo", ....)
```

However, generally you should not be doing this for the following reasons

1. It creates an ugly query string
2. The query string that it generates could exceed the query string
   limit and throw and exception
3. If you model contains any properties which are complex objects or
   collections, model binding will fail and those properties will be
   null

Instead, you should pass the ID of the model to the GET method, and get the model from your repository (database, Session etc), for example

```
@Html.DialogFormLink("Update", Url.Action("UpdatePhoto", new { id = Model.ID }), "Update Photo", ....)
```

and in the controller

```
public ActionResult UpdatePhoto(int ID)
```