# Jquery click doesn't work twice

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, crud

I'm trying to write CRUD operations using ajax. Here some code:
These are my View classes:

```
//PhotoSummary
@model PhotoAlbum.WEB.Models.PhotoViewModel
<div class="well">
    <h3>
        <strong>@Model.Name</strong>
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary">@Model.AverageRaiting.ToString("# stars")</span>
    </h3>
    <span class="lead">@Model.Description</span>
    @Html.DialogFormLink("Update", Url.Action("UpdatePhoto", new {photoId = @Model.PhotoId}), "Update Photo", @Model.PhotoId.ToString(), Url.Action("Photo"))
</div>

//Main View
@model PhotoAlbum.WEB.Models.PhotoListViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Photos";
}
@foreach (var p in @Model.Photos)
{
    <div id=@p.PhotoId>
        @Html.Action("Photo", new {photo = p})
    </div>
}
```

The sript:

```
$('.dialogLink').on('click', function () {
    var element = $(this);       
    var dialogTitle = element.attr('data-dialog-title');
    var updateTargetId = '#' + element.attr('data-update-target-id');
    var updateUrl = element.attr('data-update-url');
    var dialogId = 'uniqueName-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
    var dialogDiv = "<div id='" + dialogId + "'></div>";

    $(dialogDiv).load(this.href, function () {
        $(this).dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            title: dialogTitle,
            close: function () { $(this).empty(); },
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    // Manually submit the form                        
                    var form = $('form', this);
                    $(form).submit();
                },
                "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog('close'); }
            }
        });

        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(this);
        wireUpForm(this, updateTargetId, updateUrl);
    });
    return false;
});});


function wireUpForm(dialog, updateTargetId, updateUrl) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        if (!$(this).valid())
            return false;
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {

                if (result.success) {
                    $(dialog).dialog('close');
                    $(updateTargetId).load(updateUrl);
                } else {             
                    $(dialog).html(result);
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(dialog);

                    wireUpForm(dialog, updateTargetId, updateUrl);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

And here my Tag builder:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DialogFormLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string dialogContentUrl,
         string dialogTitle, string updateTargetId, string updateUrl)
    {
        TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("a");
        builder.SetInnerText(linkText);
        builder.Attributes.Add("href", dialogContentUrl);
        builder.Attributes.Add("data-dialog-title", dialogTitle);
        builder.Attributes.Add("data-update-target-id", updateTargetId);
        builder.Attributes.Add("data-update-url", updateUrl);
        builder.AddCssClass("dialogLink");
        return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
    }
```

So, I have major problem if the dialog was called twice without the calling page being refreshed:
it just redirects me to the action page. 
The question is how to update @Html.Action without reloading the page?
Could anyone help me?

Comment: You have not given enough information to be sure (you need to show the html your generating). Assuming your custom `@Html.DialogFormLink()` method is generating a `<a>` element with `class=".dialogLink"`, then I'm guessing its replacing the contents of `<div id=@p.PhotoId>` with a new partial view containing a `@Html.DialogFormLink()` method. If that is the case, you need to use event delegation, so the script needs to be `$(document).on('click', '.dialogLink', function() { ....`

Comment: Although its best to replace `document` with the closest ancestor which exists when you first render the page - e.g. `<div id="xxx">@foreach (var p in @Model.Photos) { ... }</div>` and then `$(#xxx).on(...`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you very much! Using 'document' works fine! If I replasce it by the ancestor I have System.Web.HttpException: "Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'."

Comment: If that's the case, you have made an error somewhere :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yep! My fault. Made a misprint. Could you explain what's going on? I don't understand why do I need to add one more id or use #'document'? Also you can post your comments as an answer!

Comment: Sure, but can you edit your question to include a sample of the html generated by your `@Html.DialogFormLink()` method so it makes sense to others as well

Comment: @StephenMuecke Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@foreach` loop in the main view is generating a partial view for each `Photo` which in turn is creating a link with `class="dialogLink"`.

Your script handles the click event of these links and replaces it with a new link with `class="dialogLink"`. But the new link does not have a `.click()` handler so clicking on the new (replacement) link does not activate your script.

Instead you need to use event delegation to handle events for dynamically generated content using the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method (refer also [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for more information on event delegation). Note also that your current use of `$('.dialogLink').on('click', function () {` is the equivalent of `$('.dialogLink').click(function () {` and is not using event delegation. It attaches a handler to elements that exist in the DOM at the time the page is loaded, not to elements that might be added in the future.

Change your html to

```
<div id="photos">
    @foreach (var p in @Model.Photos)
    {
        <div class="photo">@Html.Action("Photo", new { photo = p })</div>
    }
</div>
```

and then modify the script to

```
$('#photos').on('click', '.dialogLink', function() { 
    ....
});
```

Side note: There is no real need to add an `id=@p.PhotoId` to the containing `div` element and you could use `<div class="photo">` as per above, and then reference it by using `var updateTargetId = $(this).closest('.photo');` and delete the `builder.Attributes.Add("data-update-target-id", updateTargetId);` line of code from your `DialogFormLink()` method